# Does lava count as a trap?

Tags: hades

I am fighting through Asphodel, and have a Chaos boon that temporarily increases my damage taken by traps by 370%. Does lava count as a trap for the purposes of this boon? Or will I be more than fine just taking this penalty since there are no spike traps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From experience I can say, **yes**.
The lava counts as "traps" and those Chaos Boons can be really deadly in Asphodel.

Here's a picture of me taking some usually 1 damage lava tics while holding just such Chaos boon.
[image]

Be careful when fighting Learnie with such boon.

Comment: If you are not yet at the point where Zag starts to troll, Learnie is the Hydra, FYI.

Comment: To add to this, I've used Athena's reduced trap damage boon and saw that it did *less* damage on magma.